# Which class is Mark sitting in when he falls asleep?

Tags: the-social-network

In the movie "The Social Network" - which class is Mark sitting in when he falls asleep? He then wakes up and answers the question.

I think it might be Computer Architecture.

Comment: He doesn't fall asleep in the class.

Comment: There is some more discussion on this here: http://chomaloma.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/social-network-inaccuracies-regarding.html

Comment: Are you referring to this scene? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3Rt2_9d7Jg Or this scene https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9W-NkB44Fk?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am not sure if I am remembering a different scene, as it has been a while since I watched the movie, but I thought it was an Operating Systems lecture (CS 161. Operating Systems). I searched for Operating Systems lecture and The Social Network, and came across [a blog by the lecturer who was portrayed in the film](http://matt-welsh.blogspot.com/2010/10/in-defense-of-mark-zuckerberg.html).

> The question: Suppose we’re given a computer with a 16-bit virtual address and a page size of 256 bytes.The system uses one-level page tables, that start at address 0x0400. Maybe you want to have DMA on your 16-bit system, who knows? The first few pages are reserved for hardware flags, etc. Assume page table entries have eight status bits. The eight status bits would be?
>
>  Mark's reply: 1 valid bit, 1 modify bit, 1 reference bit and 5 permission bits

It sounds like the right scene.

Comment: This isn't the correct scene, the quoted scene took place in a large room with no computers in it with the lecturer/professor at the front of the room, while the scene in question took place in a small square room full of computers

Comment: Further expansion - the scene quoted in this answer is the one where the girl at the front has the piece of paper with "u dick" written on it passed back to Mark, prompting him to get up and leave the class before delivering his line on the way out. It is this scene which leads up to Mark meeting the Winklevii.

Answer (score 3):

He falls asleep in a business meeting with a venture capitalist.  IIRC, it was the first meeting that Eduardo set up, and it's set up in a flashback where he says something like, "He came, but I wish he stayed home."

He **walks out** of a class after being handed a note from a girl that said, "u dick".  It's on his way out of that classroom, after being ridiculed by the professor for "giving up", that he rattles off the correct answer.

Comment: He doesn't fall asleep during the meeting. He keeps making that sound with his mouth.